# JAVA evaluating multiple OR conditions in IF statement

Tags: java, if-statement

How do I correctly code this statement? Is there a better way?

```
byte[] buf = rtm.getMessageData();
if (buf[0] == 'A'|| 'B' || 'C' || 'D' || 'E' || 'F')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact analogue of your code in correct Java would be:

```
if (buf[0] == 'A'|| buf[0] == 'B' || buf[0] == 'C'
        || buf[0] == 'D' || buf[0] == 'E' || buf[0] == 'F')
```

but as you've surmised, there are better ways.

One option:

```
if (buf[0] >= 'A' && buf[0] <= 'F') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Another option:

```
switch (buf[0]) {
    case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
        ...
        break;
    default:
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (buf[0] >= 'A' && buf[0] <= 'F')
    ....
```